# Should I add new players to my mailing list?

Tags: marketing

I wonder if it's ok for me to add new player's emails to my mailing list. Should I display a notice or something before doing so? I don't see these a lot in popular mobile games, but they send emails anyway from time to time.

Answer (score 4):

You should ask before signing users up for a email list. Doing so doesn't harm the users who are interested, but *can* make the users who aren't interested upset with you. So it's generally the "nice" thing to do.

In some jurisdictions, there may be law that *require* you to only offer opt-in email lists, or require you to present opt-out notices in certain ways, et cetera. The most recent such law I'm aware of is the [EU's GDPR](https://eugdpr.org), which has some sections pertaining to email marketing.

You should consult your lawyer for specific legal advice regarding your situation and the game you plan to ship.

Comment: [I believe Canada's laws also require explicit opt-in](https://www.cyberimpact.com/en/why-email-marketing-is-different-in-canada/).

Answer (score -3):

yes.. you can as the email is the only way to connect with people around the world nowadays. but another reminder is to make sure that your email notification won't be like a spam to others. make sure to send the information email only.